# Filter a spark dataframe based on column datatypes

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe with col_a and col_b and both are written as "String" in the parquet file I receive. col_b could be an int or a string and I want to filter out all rows where col_b is not an int.

```
Input:
col_A   col_b
1       "abc"
2       "3"
3       "xyz"

Output:
col_a   col_b
2       3
```

I understand I need to typecast, but not sure how to proceed beyond that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` operation on your dataframe for filtering the non Integer values. Create a UDF that will accept the column value and returns `true` if the value can be converted to `Int` else it returns `false`.

```
//your original DF
val df = Seq((1, "abc"),
  (2, "3"),
  (3, "xyz")).toDF("col_a", "col_b")

//create a udf for filter function
val isValueInt = udf((value: String) => Try(value.toInt).isSuccess)

//apply the filter on DF
df.filter(isValueInt($"col_b")).show(false)

//    output
//    +-----+-----+
//    |col_a|col_b|
//    +-----+-----+
//    |1    |3    | 
//    +-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 4):

UDF is really not required here. You can `cast` the column as `int` and it will return `null` wherever it fails and then filter the non-null rows.

```scala
val df = Seq((1, "abc"),
             (2, "3"),
             (3, "xyz")).toDF("col_a", "col_b")

df.filter( $"col_b".cast("int").isNotNull ).show

//+-----+-----+
//|col_a|col_b|
//+-----+-----+
//|    2|    3|
//+-----+-----+
```